# Selenium Webdriver java : unable to click on OK button (span tag in button tag)

Tags: java, button, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
<div id="sieb-ui-popup-mvg-selected" class="AppletStylePopup">
    <form onsubmit="return false;" action="/ecom_enu/start.swe" method="post" name="SWEForm4_0">
        <div class="siebui-popup-btm siebui-mvg-btn-modifier">
            <span class="siebui-popup-button">
                <button id="s_4_1_79_0_Ctrl" class="siebui-ctrl-btn siebui-icon-closeapplet s_4_1_79_0 appletButton" aria-label="Responsibilities:OK" title="Responsibilities:OK" tabindex="0" data-display="OK" name="s_4_1_79_0" type="button">
                    <span>OK</span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to click on the OK button. Please help, Thanks!

I have tried with the below, but it does not work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".siebui-ctrl-btn.siebui-icon-closeapplet.appletButton")).click();
```

Also tried likethis, it does not work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*button[@title='Responsibilities:OK']/span[contains(text(),'OK]")).click();
```

Also tried the below, it does not work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(span/text(), 'OK')]")).click();
```

Also tried the below, it does not work. Timeout error occurred

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0"));
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'OK')]")));
el.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: This HTML is wrong - for example there is an opening tag `<table ...>` but I can't see a closing tag `</table>`. There are two opening tags `<div>` within the form, but only one closing tag `</div>`. Is this real html code of your page ? When I am trying to run this HTML code on JSFiddle, then it is not rendered at all, it is damaged.

Comment: Thanks krokodilko. There were three lines which were collapsed when I copied here, so I have removed them. Updated the HTML code now.

Comment: TImeout error occurs in which statement in the last case. Frame or button?

Comment: When I executed document.getElementsByTagName("frame") in the browser console, I dont get any result. So I think it is not a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting xpath using `firebug` and `firepath` add on of firefox. You ll definitely be able to solve your problem. If you aren't aware how to capture xpath using firebug then refer [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) link and let me know in case of any issues. You should add firebug and firepath to your firefox first before capturing xpath

Comment: yep, added firepath. the xpath of the OK button is

Comment: yep, using firepath only. the xpath of the OK button is ".//*[@id='s_4_1_79_0_Ctrl']". Here the number "4" keep changing every time. the absolute path is "/html/body/div[9]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/span/button". This button is one of the buttons on a popup applet. Clicking on this OK button will close this popup applet window and return to the earlier main screen at the background. I am able to click on other buttons in the same popup applet window, but unable to click on only this OK button. I have tried many ways as explained in the post.

Comment: Okay then try this code. It should resolve your problem driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class=siebui-ctrl-btn siebui-icon-closeapplet s_4_1_79_0 appletButton").click();

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below ways -

First get the root element and keep it to a WebElement object. Then find the Ok button element and a click.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sieb-ui-popup-mvg-selected > form > div"));
makeWait(5);  //Set any value you need for wait until appearing Ok Button       
elem.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='button']")).click();
```

Create another local or global method for wait some moments

```
/*
 * make some wait the execution
 */
public void makeWait(int waitForSecond)
{
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(1000 * waitForSecond);
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000 * waitForSecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You can also try removing the makeWait() if you don't need. Probably It may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code, may be this should work,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'siebui-popup')]//span[text()='OK']")).click();
```

Try using Firepath in Mozilla, so that you can get the correct path by checking with different combinations of CSS and XPATH. It will give you the correct idea of using the selectors for identifying an element.